# How does one create product collections in Ubercart?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, e-commerce, drupal-modules, ubercart

I thought i could use the 'attributes' feature for this, but unfortunately the way it displays the cost for each item is too limiting. How do I group products together in ubercart (e.g. a group of glassware all by the same designer) with an option to purchase the entire collection or individual items?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe what you are after is the **product kit module** (shipped with ubercart) maybe in addition to a **dedicated taxonomy**.

The **product kit module** allows you to group products in kits, so that you can actually add to your cart the entire kit rather than its individual components.

Kit creation gives you various options such as for example:

- The user can see what the kit is made of or not ("Bohemian set" vs. "1 x Big glass + 1 x Little glass + 1 x Saucer").
- The user can change the individual amount of kit elements or only the number of kits purchased ("3 x Bohemian kits" vs "3 x Big glasses + 0 x Small glasses + 3 x Saucer").

With the **catalog view and a dedicated taxonomy** you can then present products and kits on the basis of the terms you used to mark them. For example http://example.com/products/bohemian might display the bohemian kit plus all the glasses and saucers.

Beware that **the kit is always "expanded" as a list of products, when the cart is turned into an order** (i.e.: In the order you will never find "kits" but always "glasses and saucers").

HTH!

Comment: dude. thats a great answer, but i am afraid your link is broken.

Comment: @Oded: what link? The example.com link? :D This must be a joke... :D